# How to make filling bars with different color depending on value? Looking for JS solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, charts

I'm looking for solution to create live-charts like shown on the picture, I've looked through samples of Highcharts, fusioncharts, raphaeljs and much much more others, but couldn't find something really appropriate. I've tried a lot with fusioncharts LED widgets, but it doesn't have required customization possibilities. Looking for your help and advice, thanks!

Take a look at the picture, please. I need bars with same way of working and look&feel.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdGLz.png

Comment: we need to see what you tried and what html structure you are using in order to help you :)

Comment: Did you try it with d3.js? It's slightly harder to learn but you can get a great deal of customization possibility out of it.

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/3/

Comment: that doesn't really matter what html structure  do I use, i can use any js-framework. I just need to get working bars as shown on the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the CSS part you could go with a background-image or gradient and hide it partially with an inset shadow.

Javascript would need to update one value of inset shadow: **[CSS only DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wrsCk)**

```
 box-shadow:inset 0 90px #333 /* this would be 10% for a 100px bar */
```

Comment: That is really awesome thing and what I need! Thank you, I'll probably use this code =)

Answer (score 0):

I would go about this by saying something along the lines of : if value is > than 10(value) change color. Look into using JQuery to change color of divs with .css command. To make the bars move you should also look into JQuery with .animate() If you haven't already go to www.codecademy.com and go through the JQuery tutorial. 
This might not have given you the code straight up but you'll learn more from trying to work it out with those resources. Hope it helped though =)

Comment: Yeah, I'll probably will have to do that bars with pure jQuery, because despaired to find some library which could do that for me fast and accurate. There will be much more coding, but I don't see other solution.

Comment: It's probably the easiest way, if you are not doing the coding for your own interest though you could always ask someone to code it for you, though it shouldn't be too difficult =)

Comment: Try something like this, it's hard as I don't know what your input is for the values so I have set it to random -- refresh the page a few times http://jsfiddle.net/7o2wsv7b/3/